# Is a win32 timer owned by its calling thread?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is a win32 timer (Created by `SetTimer()`) owned by its calling thread (So that calling `TerminateThread()` to the calling thread will destroy the timer)?

Comment: Yes, timers are "owned" by the thread that created them.

Comment: As a small note... you should not try to kill a thread "from the outside", what you do normally is just set a flag and have the thread checking periodically if a quit has been requested and then exit the thread "voluntarily". Killing from outside is a source of a lot of problems and should never be used except as a last resort and in very controlled cases otherwise you risk all sort of leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timer belongs to the thread that invoked `SetTimer`.  It can optionally be associated with an HWND (window handle) which also have similar thread affinity.

If the thread exits or is killed, all the timers on that thread die with it regardless if `KillTimer` is invoked.  There's no message pump to dispatch those WM_TIMER messages anymore when the owning thread dies.

And if the timer is associated with an HWND, the timer is also implicitly destroyed when the HWND is destroyed.

With all that in mind, it's a good idea to invoke `KillTimer` explicitly that let the timer object get implicitly cleaned up.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie a thread without a message pump can't use timers (not this sort of timer, anyway)